# How to add participant in onlineMeetings graph API who are not active directory users

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to add attendees in graph API for scheduling online meeting. Here I can see that API takes identity-> user -> id which is active directory id. but in my use case we want to add participants which are not part of active directory. so below API works for active directory users.

```
let data = {
  startDateTime: '2023-07-13T14:30:34.2444915-05:30',
  endDateTime: '2023-07-13T15:00:34.2464912-05:30',
  subject: 'Meeting with external participants2',
  isOnlineMeeting: true,
  allowAttendeeToEnableCamera: true,
  allowAttendeeToEnableMic: true,
  allowMeetNow: true,
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "upn": "abc@onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "attendees": [
      {
        "upn": "user1@onmicrosoft.com",
        "identity": {
          "user": {
            "id": "a289c0ee-12d1-469f-be00-xyzavcddddd"
          }
        }
      },

      {
        "upn": "user2@onmicrosoft.com",
        "identity": {
          "user": {
            "id": "1694c8f8-1db2-418e-8d9e-huwhdfiuhw"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  const headers = {
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

axios.post(endpoint, data, { headers: headers })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error.response.data);
  });
```

But I am trying to specify non active learners like below, but it does now work.

```
  attendees: [
    {
      emailAddress: {
        address: 'abc@gmail.com',
        name: 'ABC'
      },
      type: 'required'
    },
    {
      emailAddress: {
        address: 'xyz@gmail.com',
        name: 'XYZ'
      },
      type: 'optional'
    }
  ]
```

So how to add participant in onlineMeetings graph API who are not active directory users.

Comment: there're 2 ways to [create online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/choose-online-meeting-api#comparing-the-apis) via graph api.  I found that when I create teams meeting, I can enter external users, so I'm afraid one of the api should work, could you pls try another api?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in the comments,to Create an onlineMeeting object with a custom specified external ID. If the external ID already exists, this API will return the onlineMeeting object with that external ID.

[image]

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am able to create meeting with users who are part of Active directory. But when I pass users who are not part of AD, it does not work. 

like {
      emailAddress: {
        address: 'abc@gmail.com',
        name: 'ABC'
      },
      type: 'required'
    },

Comment: We have tested this and able to create meeting with gmail ID user.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgMOs.png